# Set a column value equal to another column with a trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two columns, Id and Descrizione.
I want to set id = descrizione when a user insert a form. How can i do this with a trigger?

I've tried this but it not works

```
create or replace TRIGGER RUOLI_ID
BEFORE INSERT ON ruoli
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :new.id IS NULL THEN

        SET :new.id = Descrizione;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: If this is the only thing that the trigger needs to do, you could reduce its impact on performance using a WHEN clause, e.g. `create or replace trigger ruoli_id before insert on ruoli for each row WHEN NEW.id IS NULL begin :new.id := :new.descrizione; end;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ruoli_id
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON ruoli
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.id := NVL (:new.id, :new.descrizione);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WHEN` clause which will execute the trigger only when `ID` is null, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RUOLI_ID 
    BEFORE INSERT ON RUOLI
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    :NEW.ID := :NEW.DESCRIZIONE;
END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It says me " invalid new or old specification"

Comment: ok, Updated the answer to replace `ID` with `NEW.ID` in `WHEN` clause

Comment: Already done, but i got these two errors:
-"PL/SQL Statement ignored"
-"identifier DESCRIZIONE must be declared"